# I am facing problems while implementing login functionality of my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

There is an issue with the login functionality of an app. The code provided is shown below. The issue causing runtime errors is highlighted in the provided images.

```js
const loginUser = async () => {
  // Field Validation
  if (!login.username || !login.password) {
    setError('Please Fill in All Fields');
    return;
  }

  let response = await API.userLogin(login);

  if (
    response.msg === 'Username does not match' ||
    response.msg === 'Password does not match'
  ) {
    setError('Username or password is incorrect');
    return;
  }

  if (response.isSuccess) {
    setError('');

    sessionStorage.setItem(
      'accessToken',
      `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`
    );
    sessionStorage.setItem(
      'refreshToken',
      `Bearer ${response.data.refreshToken}`
    );

    setAccount({
      username: response.data.username,
      name: response.data.name,
    });
    isUserAuthenticated(true);
    navigate('/');
  } else {
    setError('Something Went Wrong !!');
  }
};

export const loginUser = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ username: request.body.username });

    if (!user) {
      return response
        .status(401)
        .json({ msg: 'Username does not match' });
    }
    let match = await bcrypt.compare(
      request.body.password,
      user.password
    );

    if (!match)
      return response
        .status(401)
        .json({ msg: 'Password does not match' });

    if (match) {
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        user.toJSON(),
        process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
        { expiresIn: '15m' }
      );
      const refreshToken = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY);

      const newToken = new Token({ token: refreshToken });
      await newToken.save();

      response.status(200).json({
        accessToken: accessToken,
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
        name: user.name,
        username: user.username,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response
      .status(500)
      .json({ msg: 'Error while logging in the user' });
  }
};
```

What errors are occurring with this code? Can someone help fix this issue? There are two images showing the runtime error and message, respectively: [Runtime Error is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFsvL.png) and [Msg is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQmgx.png).

Comment: Please share the screenshots of response in network tab, so we can understand the error in more precise way.

Comment: Just click on these link ..Runtime Error is showing and Msg is okay.